# Making a A2lix translation field required in the front end in a Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, sylius, a2lix-translation

Is there a way to make a [A2lix translation](https://github.com/a2lix) field required and validated through the front-end in a Symfony form? I have tried adding a property of `presentation` and `translations` to my `validation.yml` file, but to no avail.

I find that when I don't enter anything in the translation field the form doesn't submit, but nothing happens. No FE or BE error.

My form:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translationsForms', array(
            'form_type' => new CourseGuideTranslationType($this->dataClass . 'Translation', $this->validationGroups),
            'label'     => 'crmpicco.course_guide.name',
            'required'  => true
        ))
        ->add('name', 'text');
}
```

In `validation.yml`:

```
CRMPicco\GolfBundle\Entity\CourseGuide:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

`CourseGuideTranslationType.php`:

```
class CourseGuideTranslationType extends AbstractResourceType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('presentation', 'text', array(
                'required' => true,
                'label'    => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'crmpicco_course_guide_translation';
    }
}
```